# Want to check certain values are present in the excel sheet with python

Tags: python, pandas, automation

i have an excel sheet and i want to check if particular value is there

[image]

the code is

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\abdul_saboor\\PycharmProjects\\sleneiumpythonsession\\venv\\LoginData.xlsx")
first_sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
particular_cell_value = first_sheet.rows
particular_cell_value1 = first_sheet.columns
for x in  particular_cell_value:
    for j in particular_cell_value1:
        if "adm@yourstore.com" in particular_cell_value1:
            print("Test case passed")
        else:
            print("Failed")
```

but the output is displaying failed everytime? i want to check if adm@yourstore.com is there or not.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('LoginData.xlsx')

isin = 'adm@yourstore.com' in df['username'].tolist()

print(f"User adm@yourstore.com is in file: {'yes' if isin else 'no'}")
```

Comment: if i want o paramterize it    print(f""+ valuetocheck +" is in file:"+{'yes' if isin else 'no'}+"").. passing valuetocheck to he function                                                                                        
def checkstring(valuetocheck,str_columnname,file_path):
 df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
 is_present = valuetocheck in df[str_columnname].tolist()
print(f""+ valuetocheck +" is in file:"+{'yes' if isin else 'no'}+"")
valuetocheck=""
str_columnname=""
file_path=''
checkstring(valuetocheck,str_columnname,file_path)
 NameError: name 'isin' is not defined